# How to get helper method value in knockout js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I created this method in helper :

```
public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

I need to display above output in knockout js. I dont know how to get helper method value in knockout js file. Please help me to come out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to a php function value to js files means knockout js then

You have to store to js variable.

So create a phtml and call this phtml using our layout.

Create default.xml at `app/design/frontend/<VendorName>/<ThemeName>/Magneto_Theme/layout/default.xml` theme folder and call

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="YourBLockName" template="Magento_Theme::html/js-variable.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> ```
> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/js-variable.phtml
> ```

**And print call this  helper function**

```
 <script>
        window.mymessageValue = "<?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(YourHelperClass::class)->getMessage() ?>";
    </script>
```

At knockout js you can get that php function value by using 
 window  vairable `window.mymessageValue`.

Comment: Thank you @Amit Bera 
This is useful  for me (y)